# jQuery send POST parameters to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

This is how I'm trying to send some data to a php file:

```
function requestWsList(functionToProcess, me) {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;


    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        traditional: true,
        url: urlWS(),
        contentType: "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "html",  
        type: "POST",
        data: {name: 'value', anotherName: 'another value'},
        processData: false,
        success:function(data) {
            functionToProcess(data, me);
        } });

}
```

When I call this javascript function, the php request is triggered but I always get an empty array in the php variable $_POST.

What am I doing wrong? What do I have to do to read the "name" and "anotherName" variables in PHP?

Comment: Does the console show any errors? Please show us your PHP code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert your JSON object into a string.  For example:

```
data: '{ "name": "value", "anotherName": "another value" }
```

If you're using a browser that supports it you can use JSON.stringify()

For example:

```
data: JSON.stringify({name: 'value', anotherName: 'another value'});
```

Answer (score 1):

You set `contentType` to `"text/xml;charset=UTF-8"` and you are passing a JavaScript object. Just remove this parameter and it should work.

Comment: not only I needed to remove the "contentType", I also had to what @Delosdos suggested (stringify my data).
I wish I could set both answers as correct.